# How does the if statement work and why should I set a value prior to checking a condition?

Tags: theming

```
{% set switch_check = true %}

{% if switch_check == 'Small' %}
      {{ content.field_value }}
 {% elseif switch_check == 'Large' %}
      {{ content.field_other_value }}
{% endif %}
```

I want to check if `content.switch_check == 'Small'` then print `content.field_value` else if `content.switch_check == 'Large'` then print `content.field_other_value`

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to check `content.switch_check`, why not `{% if content.switch_check %}`? Your current code will never work as you want it to, `switch_check` will always be `true`, never `'Small'` or `'Large'`, because you've declared it as such

Comment: I'd consider questions about Twig in general as off-topic TBH. Twig is nothing Drupal-specific.

Comment: @Clive Thanks for the quick response. {% if content.switch_check %} this is working and being true on both cases when it is 'Small' or 'Large'

Comment: That only checks the "truthiness" of the value stored in `content.switch_check`. You might need to read up on Boolean values -- `if` just evaluates an expression and executes code if the expression evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missing something.

You're setting a value to `true` and then checking whether it's `'Small'` or `'Large'`.

This will never return true, as seen below:

```
{% if true == 'Small' %}
      {{ content.field_value }}
 {% elseif true == 'Large' %}
      {{ content.field_other_value }}
{% endif %}
```

You may as well check whether `1 == 0` or `true == false`.

**EDIT:** Also, as Clive says in his comment above:

> If you want to check `content.switch_check`, why not `{% if content.switch_check %}`?

In other words, you're not even checking the thing you say you want to check.

In your own words:

> I want to check `if content.switch_check == 'Small'` then print `content.field_value` else `if content.switch_check == 'Large'` then print `content.field_other_value`

So try doing it like this:

```
{% if content.switch_check == 'Small' %}
      {{ content.field_value }}
  {% elseif content.switch_check == 'Large' %}
      {{ content.field_other_value }}
{% endif %}
```

Just for sanity's sake, try printing out the value of `content.switch_check` in a debugging statement so that you know what to expect when you make this comparison! You can remove the debugging statement once you know what the expected value is.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for this detailed answer, it really helped in understanding the missing link, I used the content.switch['0']['#markup'] and was able to check successfully.